# Mocking BlobServiceClient using MOQ

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, moq-3

In my implementation code, I am fetching accountname from BlobServiceClient object. However when I try to mock it using MOQ, I see the error below. Is there a way to get around this error?

```
storageClientMock = new Mock<BlobServiceClient>();
storageClientMock.Setup(x => x.AccountName).Returns("accountname");
```

> Message:  System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x =>
> x.AccountName Non-overridable members (here:
> BlobServiceClient.get_AccountName) may not be used in setup /
> verification expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a virtual method in a class afaik, so moq wont have the means to mock it.
If there is no interface for this there is not much you can do using moq itself.